# Unzip folders recursively in a directory (preserving the folder name)

Tags: perl

I'm looking for a way to unzip multiple folder (*.zip) in a specified directory and preserving the name of each folder. I would prefer this to be a part of a Perl script. Do I need to use shell? Please suggest a way to accomplish this.

I've tried the following shell script that is called from the main Perl script:
but it only un-zipped the first folder and didn't preserve the folder name.

```
elif [[ "$process" == "unzip" ]];then
        cd $datapath
        folders="$(ls)"
        cd $home
    for ff in $folders; do
        sname=$ff
                echo $sname
        if [  ! -f $sname ];then
                        cd $datapath
                        cd $sname
                        cmd2="unzip -n '*.zip'"
                        echo $cmd2
                        cmd2=`unzip -n '*.zip'`
                        echo $cmd2
                        cmd3="gunzip -f *.gz"
                        echo $cmd3
                        cmd3=`gunzip -f *.gz`
                        echo $cmd3
                        cd $home
        fi
    done
```

in Perl script I call:

```
my $cmd2 = `perl MDL_unzip_annotate.sh /data/test_all_runs unzip`;  print "$cmd2";

**Before:**
\data\test_all_runs\SN2-63-OFA_Val_5_Chip2\Test1.zip
\data\test_all_runs\SN2-63-OFA_Val_5_Chip2\Test2.zip

**After:**
\data\test_all_runs\SN2-63-OFA_Val_5_Chip2\Test1\text_stuff.txt
\data\test_all_runs\SN2-63-OFA_Val_5_Chip2\Test2\text-stuff2.txt
```

Comment: *"it only un-zipped the first folder"* That's probably because `datapath` is a relative path. Your shell code doesn't seem to match your description of what is required. Please would you explain more clearly?

Comment: Have you cribbed that shell code from elsewhere, or does it reflect what you're actually trying to do? Please give hard examples.

Comment: @Borodin. In my case, all folders are *.zip and not *.gz. Also it doesn't preserve the name of the folder which is a must.  any other ideas? ...When  I execute the code above it unzips only the first folder and doesn't preserve the folder but dumps it's contents. thanks

Comment: I understand you have e.g. three zipfiles, `a.zip`, `b.zip`, and `c.zip` and you want to unzip them to the subdirectories (aka folders) `a`, `b`, and `c`, right? Show a bit of your directory structure. // Also: you try to run your shell script through perl (`my $cmd2 = \`perl MDL_unzip_annotate.sh ...\` `). That probably won't work.

Comment: @Perl Dog. yes, that is correct! all three: a.zip, b.zip and c.zip are in "/data/test_all_runs/test"  folder and I don't need to move them, but only unzip them. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. And you want to extract the content of "/data/test_all_runs/test/a.zip" to the (newly created) folder "/data/test_all_runs/test/a"? (and the same for b.zip, etc.)

Comment: Yes, that would be perfect! thanks

Comment: @user3781528: Please, for goodness sake, show the real directory structure. And please confirm that you have adopted the shell script; it makes a huge difference to your question.

Comment: please clarify what you mean by 'real directory structure'?  yes, I'm running  Perl Dog's script.

Comment: With "real directory structure" @Borodin means something like I put in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39732455/5830574) in the **Before** and **After** section. With _real_ filenames and directories, not something "approximately" or "like".

Comment: Please refer to where @PerlDog has posted that shell?

Comment: The original shell script posted in my question works, however, it doesn't preserve the zipped folder name. I'm going to try to change the original shell  to preserve the original folder name. Perl Dog's script doesn't work for some reason. It sees the folder but can't open it. Why is this so difficult to get to work?

Comment: @user3781528: ***"No it's not mine but it works, however, it doesn't preserve the zipped folder name"*** So it works except when it doesn't? You've picked up something from somewhere and thought you could change a few characters. That is a wonderful approach. I can't wait to read your novels!

Comment: @user3781528: Again, please give me a reference to what you call "Perl Dog's script"

Comment: it unzips the folder and dumps the files into \test_all_runs\SN2-63-OFA_Val_5_Chip2. but the original folder is gone. My novels wouldn't be very good :)

Comment: @user3781528: *"it unzips the folder and ..."*. I'm sorry, but what does all of this?

Comment: I'm referring to the shell script posted in my question.

Comment: @user3781528: You should start a new question, and clarify all of the things you've been asked here. You should give real values for all of the variables, and something like `ls -R` to show the file structure that you're dealing with

Comment: This is is really confusing. I don't understand why your code doesn't work. The directory structure is correct. It even list the name of the zipped folder when I run your code. Yet, it throws an error message...I should probably think about this some more and post another question later. Thanks

Comment: @user3781528: *"This is is really confusing"* I'm not surprised: you have the wrong expectation of what other programmers can do to help. You mustn't *ever* transplant someone else's code into your own without studying it, understanding why it works, and testing it so that it becomes your own. The rest of the world have made it as easy as they can, but in the end you need to write code to solve the problem that you're facing, and copy-pasting code and copying it back to Stack Overflow to ask for a fix will never get your system working.

Comment: When you post another question (related to this one), please add the output of `find /data/test_all_runs -printf '%M %p\n' | sort -k2`. It shows the files and directories below `/data/test_all_runs` together with their filemode. So everybody can see which is a directory and which is a file. I'm suspicious that you confuse these terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments it got clear that you have some *.zip files in the directory `/data/test_all_runs/test` and you want them to be extracted to subdirectories with the zipfile's names below that directory. For example:

**Before:**

```
/data/test_all_runs/test/a.zip
/data/test_all_runs/test/b.zip
```

**After:**

```
/data/test_all_runs/test/a.zip
/data/test_all_runs/test/a/file1_from_a.txt
/data/test_all_runs/test/a/file2_from_a.txt
/data/test_all_runs/test/a/file3_from_a.txt
/data/test_all_runs/test/b.zip
/data/test_all_runs/test/b/file1_from_b.txt
/data/test_all_runs/test/b/file2_from_b.txt
/data/test_all_runs/test/b/file3_from_b.txt
```

If I understood that right, the following code can help:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub extract_zips_to_their_folders
{
    my $source_dir = shift;

    # iterate over all *.zip files in $source_dir:
    while( my $zipfile = <$source_dir/*.zip> ) {

        # remove '.zip' from $zipfile and store the result as $tgt_dir.
        # If $zipfile is e.g. '/data/test_all_runs/test/a.zip',
        # then $tgt_dir will be '/data/test_all_runs/test/a'.
        (my $tgt_dir = $zipfile) =~ s/\.zip$//;

        # Call 'unzip' with option '-d $tgt_dir', i.e. unzip
        # the archive to the directory with the same name.
        # 'unzip' will create the directory for you.         
        system("unzip $zipfile -d $tgt_dir");
    }
}

extract_zips_to_their_folders( '/data/test_all_runs/test' );
```

It calls the external command `unzip`. As noted in another answer, there are also Perl modules available to avoid such external calls.

Comment: Then your situation (directory structure) is different from the assumption I made in the **Before** section.

Comment: here is what i says: unzip:  cannot find or open /data/test_all_runs/SN2-63-OFA_Val_5_Chip2/analysis_MD-16-1207_v1_ae0fb263-b95b-4b53-a754-6b8b5c2ed608_unfiltered_results_2016-09-26, /data/test_all_runs/SN2-63-OFA_Val_5_Chip2/analysis_MD-16-1207_v1_ae0fb263-b95b-4b53-a754-6b8b5c2ed608_unfiltered_results_2016-09-26.zip or /data/test_all_runs/SN2-63-OFA_Val_5_Chip2/analysis_MD-16-1207_v1_ae0fb263-b95b-4b53-a754-6b8b5c2ed608_unfiltered_results_2016-09-26.ZIP.

Comment: but I see that zip folder in the directory.

Comment: Here is what I use to get the full path. `opendir my $dir, "/data/test_all_runs" or die "Cannot open directory: $!";`
`my @run_folder = readdir $dir;`
`closedir $dir;`

`my $run_folder = pop @run_folder; print "The folder` `is".$run_folder."\n";`

`my $files = "/data/test_all_runs/".$run_folder;`

Comment: It prints out the  correct path. So the name of the main folder is not "test" but SN2-63-OFA_Val_5_Chip2.

Comment: Then call `extract_zips_to_their_folders( "/data/test_all_runs/$run_folder" );`.

Comment: I get the same error. It sees the file but can't open in. The directory is ############# /data/test_all_runs/SN2-63-OFA_Val_5_Chip2
unzip:  cannot find or open /data/test_all_runs/SN2-63-OFA_Val_5_Chip2/analysis_MD-16-1207_v1_ae0fb263-b95b-4b53-a754-6b8b5c2ed608_unfiltered_results_2016-09-26, /data/test_all_runs/SN2-63-OFA_Val_5_Chip2/analysis_MD-16-1207_v1_ae0fb263-b95b-4b53-a754-6b8b5c2ed608_unfiltered_results_2016-09-26.zip or /data/test_all_runs/SN2-63-OFA_Val_5_Chip2/analysis_MD-16-1207_v1_ae0fb263-b95b-4b53-a754-6b8b5c2ed608_unfiltered_results_2016-09-26.ZIP.

Comment: Sorry, but this currently turns into a chat where I should remotely analyse your filesystem contents. I don't see any error in my code. If it is given a directory that contains zipfiles, then it will unzip them to their respective directories. What happens when you open a terminal window and enter `unzip -l /data/test_all_runs/SN2-63-OFA_Val_5_Chip2/analysis_MD-16-12‌​07_v1_ae0fb263-b95b-‌​4b53-a754-6b8b5c2ed6‌​08_unfiltered_result‌​s_2016-09-26.zip`?

Comment: it listed all 34 files in that folder

Comment: I figure out what the problem was, apparently the zip folder names were too long or perhaps there was some weird characters? When I truncated the folder names to 25 characters your code executed fine. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Nice to hear that, but it's really astonishing that `unzip` doesn't complain and shows no error message. Actually I cannot believe that, but so be it.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like Archive::Extract. From the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Extract.html):

```
use Archive::Extract;

### build an Archive::Extract object ###
my $ae = Archive::Extract->new( archive => 'foo.tgz' );
# but it works with zip as well!

### extract to cwd() ###
my $ok = $ae->extract;

### extract to /tmp ###
my $ok = $ae->extract( to => '/tmp' );

### what if something went wrong?
my $ok = $ae->extract or die $ae->error;
```

Comment: I don't think I have Archive:Extract. i have Perl 7. thanks

Comment: What does `perl -v` say? I have a hard time believing you have perl 7. Most people use perl 5 and perl 6 is in use by some, but is a different language. By the way, you can test if you have Archive::Extract by typing `perl -MArchive::Extract -E "say 1"`. If you see 1 you have the module. I chose Archive::Extract because it was a 'core' module for a long time and because you *probably* have it. But installing modules is also not difficult: http://learn.perl.org/modules/

Comment: Sorry, I have perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 29 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Comment: That means you typically would have the Archive::Extract module installed on your system.

Comment: perl -MArchive::Extract -E "say 1"
Can't locate Archive/Extract.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).

Comment: On what platform are you? `sudo yum install perl-core` on CentOS/RHEL/Fedora, `sudo apt-get install libarchive-extract-perl` on debian/ubuntu.

Comment: just to make sure..your code will list all core modules, correct and it's safe?

Comment: Yes, `perl-core` is the meta package that contains all core packages for perl on Red Hat and Fedora. Because on those platforms, the `perl` package only has a minimal set of modules. Installation is really not a problem.

Comment: Usually you wouldn't trust someone from the internet who says "Yes, install that, it's safe!". But in this case MichielB is right.

Comment: Well, also I did not point to a dodgy executable on some strange website, but to just use the repositories and packages of the Linux they are already using.

Comment: Yes, @MichielB. It was absolutely not meant as an offense. That's why I'm sure the OP can trust you here and install as you suggested.